# How to get the id of an element ON PAGE LOAD using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I simply know how to get the id of a clicked element it's like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
console.log($(this).attr("id"));
}
```

but what can I do for getting the id  on web page load? Look at this..

```
$("button").ready(function(){
console.log($(this).attr("id"));
}
```

it returns the whole document object and this one ..

```
$("button").load(function(){
console.log($(this).attr("id"));
}
```

simply does nothing.

I want to dynamically change the styles of all buttons on load.

The main project is more complicated, and I don't want to use js core to do it, I want the simplicity of jQuery selector, but equivalent js approaches are appreciated.

Comment: just consider that each element has different style. and their styles are related to their ids (it's background position)

Comment: FYI to get the `id` attribute you should just use `this.id` as it saves having to create the `$()` jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to dynamically change the styles of all buttons on load.

If that is the case you can simply apply the `css` to the `button` selector on load, without needing to get the `id` of each button.

```
$(function() {
    $("button").css("background-color", "#C00");
});
```

Or better yet, put the css styling into a class and just apply a class to all the buttons:

```
$(function() {
    $("button").addClass("red-bg");
});
```

If you did want to get the `id` of each button on load, you'd need to use an array to cater for the fact there may be more than one button:

```
var buttonIds = $("button").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

However, this is a rather pointless method as you can just use `each()` to iterate over the `button` selector anyway to get access to each indiviual button element.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the all button elements in jquery and then loop on each button element to change their style -:

```
$(function()
{
    var allButtons = $('button');
    $.each(allButtons,function(index,element)
    {
        $(element).css('width','100px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(":button").each(function () {
                console.log($(this).attr("id"));
            })
        });
```